# Partial Match in an array

Tags: excel, match, array-formulas

I'm currently using "Format only cells that contain" rule to highlight websites with suspect TLDs, in Excel 2010 and that works; but I have to make a new rule for every match value. Cumbersome to maintain.

Sample Data

```
Websites B:B
rcdesign.ru
htw.pl
opx.pl

TLDs A:A
.pl
.ru
```

I have another workbook that CF based on cell value matches in another column, but it's formula uses exact matches.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,TLDs!C:C,0))
```

Because my new sheet has partial matches, the suggested formula on another forum switches the array, and the look up value, but their formula spits an error.

Suggested Formula from another forum (gives error)

```
=INDEX(A1:A4, MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(FIND(A1:A4, B1)), 0) )
```

My edit for Conditional Formatting.

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(A1:A4, B1))
```

(I want to use this formula to activate conditional formatting, so INDEX() isn't needed.)

If functional, the cells in B:B column will format conditionally. What did I do wrong? (I did use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula in my test cell C1)

I'm sorry my original question was so vaguely worded as @BruceWayne pointed out.

Comment: What's your actual question? I understand it's similar to the one in that link, but it's different enough to warrant posting it in full. Are you trying to highlight a cell that matches another? Also if you could post some sample data and what you expect to happen, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: @pnuts
I looked at #32823791 you linked, and the suggested formula
=SEARCH(D$1,B1)
Isn't an array, would I not still need to create a new formatting rule for each data value?

Answer (score 0):

I found an incredibly convoluted solution.

```
=NOT(ISNA(INDEX(A$1:A$8,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(A$1:A$8,B1)),0))))
```

This formula works as criteria for conditional formatting.

The only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to make A$1:A$8 into A:A; because any empty cells in the array cause false positives.

Comment: New convoluted solution for turning A$1:A$8 into A$1:A$99 • 

Adding multiple duplicate values to fill A9 - A99

Comment: Using this formula as criteria in conditional formatting, [.ru] will be found in [www.example.ru]; but [www.example.com] won't trigger. Allowing me to easily filter out unwanted websites. ★ I tried using a shorter formula; but apparently MATCH can't handle arrays; but I guess INDEX can.

Comment: I'm sure someone smarter than me will find a less ugly way of making it work. =•P